# Solution of a equation of matrices

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Can I find an explicit solution for the $R$ satisfying the equation $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}R^kS(R^k)^T = M,$$ where $S$ and $M$ are known real, symmetric, and square matrices.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new matrix variable $$A=R\otimes R$$
Vectorize each side of the equation to obtain
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(M) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k {\,\rm vec}(S) \cr
m &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k\,s = \Big(\frac{A}{I-A}\Big)\,s \cr
(I-A)\,m &= As  \cr
m &= A(s+m) \cr
}$$
De-vectorizing the last equation yields 
$$\eqalign{
M &= R(S+M)R^T \cr
}$$
Now, can you solve that equation?

Comment: I thought that I could solve the equation as $R = M^{1/2}(S+M)^{-1/2}$. But, now I realize that this is wrong. So, could you kindly complete your solution? Thanks in advance.